# Comment on the monotonicity of the function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f(n)=(n+1)$ $(\displaystyle \ln (n+1) + \ln \ln (n+1)-1)$ $-$ $n (\ln n + \ln \ln n)$  $\forall n$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^+$. Then is it true that $f'(n)$ $<$ $0$ for all $n$ $>$ $m$, with $m \in \mathbb R^+$? If so, then determine the value of $m$.

I have a feeling that it is false. But by differentiating $f(n)$ I can't get any conclusion. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you obtain as the derivative of $f$? That's probably worth including.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the condition of existence of $$f(x)=(x+1) (\ln(x+1)+\ln\ln(x+1)−1) − x(\ln x+\ln\ln x)$$
\begin{cases}
x+1\gt0 \Rightarrow x\gt-1\\
\ln(x+1)\gt0 \Rightarrow x+1\gt 1\\
x\gt0\\
\ln x \gt 0\Rightarrow x\gt 1
\end{cases}
As a result $\exists f(x) \forall x \in \Bbb{R}^+ | x \gt1$. Now, let $g(x) =\ln x+\ln\ln x\Rightarrow g'(x) = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x\ln x}$. Note that $$f(x) = (x+1)(g(x+1)-1)-xg(x)\Rightarrow \\f'(x) = g(x+1)-1+(x+1)g'(x+1)-g(x)-xg'(x)=\\g(x+1)-g(x)+(x+1)\left(\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{(x+1)\ln (x+1)}\right)-x\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x\ln x}\right)-1=\\g(x+1)-g(x)+\frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}-\frac{1}{\ln x}-1=\\\ln (x+1)+\ln\ln (x+1)-\ln x-\ln\ln x+\frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}-\frac{1}{\ln x}-1\\=\ln\frac{x+1}{x}+\ln\frac{\ln (x+1)}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}-\frac{1}{\ln x}-1$$
Now by evaluating $$\lim_{x\to1^+} f'(x)=\lim_{x\to1^+} \ln\frac{x+1}{x}+\ln\frac{\ln (x+1)}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}-\frac{1}{\ln x}-1=\\\lim_{x\to1^+} \ln\frac{\ln (x+1)}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{\ln x}+\lim_{x\to1^+}\ln\frac{x+1}{x}+\frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}-1=\\-\infty+\ln2+\frac{1}{\ln2}-1=-\infty$$ you see that $f'(x) \lt 0\forall x\in]1,1+\epsilon]$; moreover $$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \ln\frac{x+1}{x}+\ln\frac{\ln (x+1)}{\ln x}+\frac{1}{\ln (x+1)}-\frac{1}{\ln x}-1=\\\ln1+\ln1-\frac{1}{+\infty}-\frac{1}{+\infty}-1=\\0+0-0^+-0^+-1=-1$$ and thus you infer that $f(x)$ is asymptotic to the line $y=-x$. Generally speaking as $f'(x)$ is continuous $\forall x\ge1$, and $\lim_{x\to1^+} f'(x) = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(x) = -1$, it must be that $f'(x) \lt0\forall x\ge1$. In fact, suppose that $\exists c | f'(c) \gt0$, then for the [*Weierstrass' theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) there must be at least 2 roots of $f'(x)\in ]1,+\infty[$ but this is impossible (various proofs, for time-reasons I'll add a sketch of $f'(x)$) as this sketch shows: [image]

All things considered it can be stated that $f'(x) \lt 0 \forall x \gt 1$, thus the missing constant $m$ must be $1$.